# Error onclick Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Quiero llamar un método de mi JS y pasar una variable pero me da Uncaught ReferenceError, como puedo arreglar esto.

PHP/HTML

```
<div class="col-4 col-md-2 topbutton ">                                        
                            <input  name="cart_id" value=" <?php echo$q["product_id"]; ?>"> 
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger eliminar_cart" value="Elimina" id="<?php echo$q["product_id"]; ?>" onclick="eliminar_cart(this)">                                           
                        </div>
```

js

```
function eliminar_cart(id) {
    var cart_id = id.id;
    alert(cart_id);}
```

Comment: Acabo de correr localmente tu código y funciona bien, si quieres lo coloco como respuesta para que revises

Comment: El archivo JS donde esta la funcion  `function eliminar_cart(id)` esta separada del HTML y si agregue el archivo con el `<script>`, perdona no haber especificado desde el principio

Comment: ok agregastes o haces referencia a ese archivo JS dentro del html? es decir el archivo js lo llamas dentro del html?

Comment: si esta agregado, todo eso ya lo revise.

Comment: Dentro de ese archivo JS esa funcion esta sola? es decir no esta dentro de algun evento u otra funcion?

Comment: si esta sola, el JS esta solo para hacer esa función

Comment: OK, en que parte del html llamas el archivo? en el head o al final del body?

Comment: suelo hacerlo al final del body.

Comment: Aaron si pones la función Javascript **después** del código HTML te dará error, debes ponerla antes (en el `head`preferiblemente), eso indicará que la función ya fue cargada, ya existe en el DOM, cuando quieras usarla.

Comment: Y los valores de php para es campo y el id si lo esta seteando el php? es decir no te esta colocando esos valores o alguno de ellos en nulo? solo te da el error cuando le das click al botón? intentastes hacer un alert apenas entras a la función?

Comment: excelente @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav muchas gracias estas en lo cierto https://gph.is/2flevwQ

Comment: a su orden, que bueno que resolvistes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependiendo del valor que se retorne en `$q`, sólo es necesario colocar tu código js al inicio de tu archivo html (al inicio del `body` o en el `head`), esto entre etiquetas `<script>` o incluyendo el archivo js.

```js
function eliminar_cart(id) {
    var cart_id = id.id;
    alert("msg:" + cart_id);}
```

```html
<div class="col-4 col-md-2 topbutton ">          <input  name="cart_id" value="valorRetornadoen$q"> 
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger eliminar_cart" value="Elimina" id="idRetornadoen$q" onclick="eliminar_cart(this);">                                           
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay dos prácticas recomendadas que estás olvidando:

1. El código JS debe estar siempre dentro de un bloque `DOMContentLoaded`, de modo que no se intente nunca usar elementos del DOM antes de que éste esté totalmente cargado.
2. Conviene que nuestro código HTML sea lo más independiente posible. Por eso, evita poner funciones dentro de los elementos HTML. En el ejemplo he quitado la función que estaba dentro del botón, cambiándola por un *listener* en JS. Esto nos dará además la ventaja de `this` directamente.

Dejo el código, como una posibilidad de resolver el problema aplicando buenas prácticas.

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
    btn1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        alert(this.id);
    }, false);
  });
</script>

<div class="col-4 col-md-2 topbutton ">
  <input name="cart_id" value="Test...">
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger eliminar_cart" value="Elimina" id="btn1">
</div>
```

Comment: yo soy estudiante sigo dando mis primeros pasos, por eso suelo preguntar cosas que para algunos son simples, pero el problema del código es que lo que envié fue un fragmento del problema real, la idea del PHP es porque con un foreach me va a dar todos los articulos de la session, ademas no puedo tener un id por que el for los duplicara y no me funciona de esa manera, de  esta menara me funciona para enviarla via ajax y termine de hacer lo que necesito.

Comment: @Aaron M Fonseca entiendo, pero en el `for` puedes tener un contador que se incremente en cada interacción y usarlo para el ID, de ese modo no te los duplicará, algo así: `id="btn$i"`, suponiendo que `$i` es el valor que se incrementa en `1` a cada paso del `for`